# How can change the color of text of Pull to refresh on UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

How can change the color of the text 'loading...'?

[image]

Comment: How did you set the text loading? Where did u declare the label ?Your question is different than what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, i need to change the color of  the text 'loading...'

Comment: How did you set the text loading... ? could you pls provide some code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
//the color of the background
self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

//the color of the spinner
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// the color of the label
NSString *title = @"loading...";
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                    forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attrsDictionary];
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = attributedTitle;
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake before, see my edited answer.
I'm taking a look for change the image.

Comment: @ Picci can you please tell me how to add an icon on tableView when the user starts to pull down to refresh list